Who was mentioned in surah noor aisha bint abu bakr ra ormaria al qibtiyah ra
this is shia view that in surah noor it were the accusations of maria al qibtiyah  that were addressed and not Aisha ra can you please refute this this is creating a confusion as there were accusations going against both of them as they say
